# Can I speed up Aomei system backup using an external hard disk by local storing then copying it over?

Tags: backup

I always backup the Win 10 System to an external hard disk. We went for a cheap external so despite the USB 3 connection it is rather slow taking over 2 hours. Would saving it on the internal hard disk then copying over speed things up and how does it work with Aomei Backupper Standard?

The external HD has the following specs:
Heads   16
Cylinders   243,201
Tracks  62,016,255
Sectors 3,907,024,065
SATA type   SATA-III 6.0Gb/s
Device type Fixed
ATA Standard    ATA8-ACS
Serial Number   ZN19ALTQ
Firmware Version Number CC43
LBA Size    48-bit LBA
Power On Count  1441 times
Power On Time   81.9 days
Speed   7200 RPM
Features    S.M.A.R.T., APM, NCQ
Max. Transfer Mode  SATA III 6.0Gb/s
Used Transfer Mode  SATA III 6.0Gb/s
Interface   USB (SATA)
Capacity    1863 GB
Real size   2,000,398,934,016 bytes
RAID Type   None
S.M.A.R.T
and 256 GB free out of 1.5 TB

Comment: Its possible it will be faster, but its also possible it will be slower. There are various reasons depending on the method used. For example, if you use a special program to copy the image over that is optimized for speed, it may indeed be faster. But if your backup finishes, and you notice it 1 hour later, that by itself could make it all slower, if you catch my drift. If all is optimized, it can be slower or faster and there is no way for SuperUser to give a definitive answer to this question other than: try both and benchmark to be sure.

Comment: USB 3 relatively speaking is going to be slower than any direct attached solution.  USB 3.2 Gen 2 performance would be comparable to a direct attached solution

Answer (score 1):

That is somewhat unlikely - indeed it is likely to slow things down further.  The solution is to get (Much more expensive) SSD external storage which will greatly speed up the backup (between 2 and 8 times faster depending on the source disk and speed of the current disk. It also a lot more reliable then hdd storage provided it is plugged in at least every few months)

Comment: Every comment and answer here is smart.  That doesn't always happen. :)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly depends on your motherboard and then on your disks. You can have fast hard drives but be limited by the speed of the sata port or the usb ports. Using internal hard drives seems to be faster. Just remember, on some cases the sata ports have the same speed, on other cases the maker of parts designs a primary sata port and secondary ones with less speed, this is true in many cases for people using the DVD sata port with a hdd caddy, but on some cases (newer models?) both have the same speed, just remember, inside many computers you can have sata1, sata2, or sata3.

Things can behave similarly on USB ports. I have avoided USB backups because of this, but over the years as I upgraded my computer (changing models) found out some ports (not even tagged as 3.1/3.0) were faster, same with new "blue" usb 3+ ports.

Try yourself, do some testing and see what you find.